# Can Excel Ranges be jagged (rather than always contiguous)?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, jagged-arrays, named-ranges

One can define ranges in C# Excel Interop like so:

```
var homeHomeOnTheRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[3, 7], _xlSheet.Cells[42, 11]];
```

This range will encompass the subset of cells on the page from row 3 down to row 42, and across from columns 7 (or "G") through 11 (or "K").

What, though, if I want a "jagged" range - is it possible to concatenate an array of ranges into one range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format `sheet.Range("A1:A2,B2:B3,C3:C4")`.

Pay attention that `sheet` should be of type `dynamic` so don't use `Worksheet` class for this purpose.

**Example**

Set the specified range background color to red:

```
var range = sheet.Range("A1:A2,B2:B3,C3:C4");
range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

[image]